# Obtener producto de dos matrices generadas aleatoriamente - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, matrices, matemáticas

Tengo un programa que genera dos matrices de 3x3 con números aleatorios del 1 al 9, para que esté completo necesito obtener el resultado de la multiplicación de las matrices. Mi problema radica en que el programa no arroja ningún error, pero el producto de las dos matrices es incorrecto. Adjunto el método:

```
    static void generarMatrices()
    {
        int[,] matriz1 = new int[3, 3];
        int[,] matriz2 = new int[3, 3];
        int[,] matrizProducto = new int[3, 3];
        Random valores3 = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                matriz1[i, j] = valores3.Next(0, 9) + 1;
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
            {
                matriz2[k, l] = valores3.Next(0, 9) + 1;
            }
        }

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("La matriz 1 es: ");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(matriz1[i,j] + " | ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("La matriz 2 es: ");

        for (int k = 0; k <= 2; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l <= 2; l++)
            {
                Console.Write(matriz2[k, l] + " | ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("El producto entre las dos matrices es: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
            {
                matrizProducto[i, l] = 0;

                for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    matrizProducto[i, l] += matriz1[i, l] * matriz2[k, l];
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
            {
                Console.Write(matrizProducto[i, l] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Ese es el método completo, pero pongo énfasis en la parte donde se multiplicarían las matrices:

```
        Console.WriteLine("El producto entre las dos matrices es: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
            {
                matrizProducto[i, l] = 0;

                for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    matrizProducto[i, l] += matriz1[i, l] * matriz2[k, l];
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
            {
                Console.Write(matrizProducto[i, l] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }
```

No logro entender cuál fue mi error, o qué me falta, ya que se ejecuta sin errores, me ha costado más de la cuenta saber dónde fallo. Agradecería vuestra orientación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usemos como ejemplo una matriz 2x2.

Matriz #1

```
1 2
3 4
```

Matriz #2

```
5 6
7 8
```

En la matriz resultante, el valor correspondiente a la posición (0,0) sería el producto de la primera fila de la Matriz #1, multiplicado por la primera columna de la Matriz #2, así:

```
(1 * 5) + (2 * 7)
```

Entonces, debes multiplicar la fila de la Matriz #1 por la columna de la Matriz #2.

En el código que compartes, estás multiplicando un elemento de la Matriz #1 por una fila de la Matriz #2, así:

```
(1 * 5) + (1 * 6)
```

Prueba con `matrizProducto[i, l] += matriz1[k, l] * matriz2[i, k];`

Comment: Ha funcionado! Muchas gracias por su explicación